# Can't open apps with openUrl in iOS NativeScript Sidekick

Tags: ios, nativescript, sidekick

I tried all solutions that I found but I still obtaining the same result.

I am using NativeScript Sidekick on Windows 10, it works fine but when I want to open Google Maps,Facebook or Uber for example (with openUrl("comgooglemaps://") or openUrl("fb://")), it doesnt work. I tried adding LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to the Info.plist and nothing change.

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb</string>
            <string>fbapi</string>
            <string>fbauth2</string>
            <string>fbshareextension</string>
            <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
            <string>twitter</string>
            <string>viber</string>
            <string>whatsapp</string>
            <string>wechat</string>
            <string>line</string>
            <string>instagram</string>
            <string>kakaotalk</string>
            <string>mqq</string>
            <string>vk</string>
            <string>comgooglemaps</string>
            <string>googlephotos</string>
            <string>ha</string>
            <string>yammer</string>
        </array>
```

Someone helped me running a clean project that I create with Sidekick and openUrl() worked fine.

So... I wanted to know if my problem is because I am using Windows or maybe I need to add additional configurations.

It seems like a simple problem but I will be very grateful for any help. Thank you!

PD: With native iOs Map it works fine (openUrl("map://"))

Comment: Did you try a clean build to make sure your plist is updated in the complied binaries.